# How to scaling title showing bottom bar in Madrid theme with title length?

Tags: beamer, themes

[image]

As there is extra space in date bar I can shrink this bar to give more space in title bar. See red mark in the image.

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\logo{%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm-5pt}%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
}
\begin{document}
  \title{Resource  Allocation in Cloud Radio Access Network}
  \author[Md.Al-Helal \& Jobayed Ullah]{
  \parbox{2.5cm}{
\centering Md.Al-Helal\\Roll:SH-51}\hspace{3cm}
\parbox{2.5cm}{
{\centering Jobayed Ullah\\Roll:EK-107}}
\centering \vspace{1cm}\\Supervisor:\\Tomal Adhikary
}

\vspace{1cm}
\institute[CSEDU]{Computer Science \& Engineering\\CSEDU}
\date{February 25, 2018}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

The `Madrid` beamer theme uses the `infolines` 'outer theme' which defines the footline. The following MWE contains a redefinition of the footline. Comparing to the original, I have changed the width sepcifications of the second and third `beamercolorbox` according to the width of the title.

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.266666\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother


\logo{%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm-5pt}%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
}
\begin{document}
  \title{Resource  Allocation in Cloud Radio Access Network}
  \author[Md.Al-Helal \& Jobayed Ullah]{
  \parbox{2.5cm}{
\centering Md.Al-Helal\\Roll:SH-51}\hspace{3cm}
\parbox{2.5cm}{
{\centering Jobayed Ullah\\Roll:EK-107}}
\centering \vspace{1cm}\\Supervisor:\\Tomal Adhikary
}
\vspace{1cm}
\institute[CSEDU]{Computer Science \& Engineering\\CSEDU}
\date{February 25, 2018}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]