# In theme warsaw (in beamer), is it possible to split the footnote partition manually? My presentation title is not accommodated in the given space

Tags: beamer, footnotes, titles, presentations, author

The footnote is split equally for author and title. But I need more space for the title in exchange for the author.

Comment: Related although about the `Madrid` theme which internally loads the `infolines` outer theme, while `Warsaw` loads `split`: [How to scaling title showing bottom bar in Madrid theme with title length?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423303/134144) The approach is the same, though: Find the file `beamerouterthemesplit.sty`, copy the definition of the `footline` template to your `.tex` file, change the name of the theme and adjust the widths of the boxes (`wd=...`) that contain author and title to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the footline of the Warsaw theme like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong title}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\nobreak\hfill\usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}\usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]